# Which Design Patterns for 'event'-driven notification service for Content in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, notifications, content-management-system

I am designing a Content Management System. At the minute I am dealing with documents

```
public Enum DocAction(){
    DOCUMENTSUBMITTED,
    DOCUMENTAPPROVED,
    DOCUMENTREJECTED
}

public Enum NotificationType(){
    EMAIL,
    TEXT,
    POPUP
}

public class Newspaper(){
    private long                id;
    private map<DocAction,long> notifications;
    private long                EditorId
}

Public class Document(){
    private long      id;
    private long      newspaperId;
    private long      authorId
    private String    article
}

Public class Notification(){
    private long     id
    private map<NotificationType,long>     notifications
}
```

The rough outline of classes are above.

I want it to be on certain actions (document submitted, approved, rejected etc) a notification will be send out, depending which newspaper it was submitted to.

Then I can just go into the corresponding methods, such as 'saveDocument', check a key exists, and if it does then send the notification it is mapped to, to the editor/author.

I thought Enums was a good plan as could add or remove as many, and not all newspapers will want to use all. However I was informed this is a bad design, as e-nums are hard to manage, and will require alot of maintenance with redeploying etc.

I was wondering if there was a design pattern that was more suited to this design.

Alternatives I thought are just call a method every time, and use freemarker to determine if there should be an email sent.

Key features:

- Newspapers have notifications (may be of multiple types)
- Notifcations need to be sent out when certain actions to sometimes the editor id, sometimes the author id
- The number of events for each newspaper will vary.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a clear cut case for the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), whereby `Newspaper` and `Document` will be *Subjects* and your `Notifications` will be *Observers*.

If would not refrain from using `Enums`, since they are ideal to distinguish between *types of notifications* as well as *document actions*. I can't see how they will necessitate additional re-deployments additionally to those required by other code changes that go along with adding new notifications or media types.

Still, if it is a requirement to reconfigure the mapping between notifications, document actions and media types without server restart, you could implement some sort of database or config file based mapping.

Comment: Thanks,After looking into this my manager came back and suggested enums....

And Using similar to the observer pattern, just through spring and autowiring.

Thanks